# Why does this custom sortarray function fail to sort the array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I've been looking over Java arrays and tried to create my own SortArray() function rather than using somebody else's. If I pass the array 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] into the SortArray() function, it should return another array [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], sorting the array high to low. Instead, the function returns the exact same array as the array in the parameters. I commented what each code block should do in the code, please let me know if you find anything!

```
public static int[] sortArray(int[] array) {
    //Declare the highest value found so far
    int highest;

    //loop through every index in the array
    for (int minIndex = 0; minIndex < array.length; minIndex++) {

        //Set the current highest value to the first index
        highest = array[minIndex];

        //loop through every index past the minimum to check if there is a higher numer
        //do not check the indexes before the minIndex
        for (int i = 0 + minIndex; i < array.length; i++) {
            //Check to see if the current index is higher than the highest
            //if so, make that value the new highest and loop again from the next index
            if (array[i] > highest) {
                highest = array[i];
                minIndex ++;
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: simply, you're never updating the array.

Comment: Where are you ever changing the array? all you do is change the int `highest` and `minIndex` which is the for loop variable so you shouldn't even change that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't mutating `array` at all.  You aren't mutating elements in `array` at all either.  You are just tracking what the highest is.  Then `highest` goes away because the scope is gone.